Flash message not displaying when redirecting to the same page in Laravel Jetstream + Inertia
I'm having an issue with displaying flash messages in my Laravel Jetstream application using Inertia.js. Here is the relevant code:
In AppLayout.vue
<script setup>
import { usePage } from "@inertiajs/vue3";
import FlashMessage from "../Components/FlashMessage.vue";
import { ref, computed, onMounted } from "vue";

const { props: pageProps } = usePage();
const flashMessage = ref("");

const successMessage = computed(() => pageProps.flash.success);

onMounted(() => {
    if (successMessage.value) {
        flashMessage.value = successMessage.value;
    }
});
</script>

<div class="bg-white w-full shadow relative lg:fixed lg:top-0 z-50">
    <FlashMessage :success="flashMessage" />
</div>

In the handleInertiaRequest method:
public function share(Request $request): array
{
    return array_merge(parent::share($request), [
        'flash' => function () use ($request) {
            return [
                'success' => $request->session()->get('success'),
                'error' => $request->session()->get('error'),
            ];
        },
    ]);
}

In ClaseController:
public function destroy($id)
{
    $clase = Clase::find($id);

    $clase->delete();

    return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Clase Eliminada Exitosamente');
}

Everything seems to work fine except when the flash message is redirected to the same page. The variable pageProps doesn't seem to capture the message, even though the message is definitely being received because when I print {{$page.props.flash.success}}, it shows up on the screen.
What could be causing this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

what happens if you just print {{pageProps}} or console.log(pageProps)?

@Mr.Kenneth When I print 'pageProps.flash' in the console, it manteins null, At first, I thought the component needed to be mounted again for 'flashMessage.value' to be updated, but then I realized that 'pageProps.flash.success' is not updating. Now, I don't know what to do

Does this answer your question? Laravel Inertia JS Flash Messages shows only once

Check the accepted answer, the way how the flash message was returned. In the answer, the flash key has an array type value. Meaning you can just add a new entry before or after the error

Can we see the request from the front-end ?
If you used only, you have to request flash too.
